Violación de segmento (`core' generado) en C++
Hola muy buenas con todos,
Por fin logre entender el funcionamiento de los array en c++, y jugando con el código hice un script de arrays, empezando con el unidimensional, luego bidimensional, pase al tridimensional y perfecto, pense que ya era experto en arrays, ja, pero cuando quise hacer la tetradimensional me salio el error de "Violación de segmento (`core' generado)", que según hasta donde he investigado, ee un error que tiene relación con espacios de memoria no permitidos a los que el escript quiere acceder, ahora no se si deba a los recursos de mi máquina antigua con 4GB de RAM y Linux Mint, pero habria a posibilidad de expandir el recurso SWAP para poder mejorar el rendimiento o que consejo me daría para este caso en particular, igual les dejo el código ya que los array son en base a 3 elementos, yo diria que son pequeños.
Desde ya les agradezco la atención a la presente.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // array unidimensional
    cout << "Imprimiendo array Unidimensional" << endl;
    int valores1[3] {10, 11, 12};
    int longitud=sizeof(valores1)/sizeof(valores1[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++) {
        cout << valores1[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    // array bidimencional
    int valores2[3][3];
    longitud=sizeof(valores2)/sizeof(valores2[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<longitud; j++) {
            valores2[i][j]=rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    cout << "Imprimiendo array bidimensional" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<longitud; j++) {
            cout << valores2[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    // array tridimensional
    int valores3[3][3][3];
    longitud=sizeof(valores3)/sizeof(valores3[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<longitud; j++) {
            for (int k=0; k<longitud; k++) {
                valores3[i][j][k]=rand() % 100;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Imprimiendo array tridimensional" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++) {
       cout << "Imprimiendo cubo [" << i+1 << "] de la capa [" << i+1 << "]" << endl;
        for (int j=0; j<longitud; j++) {
            for (int k=0; k<longitud; k++) {
                cout << valores3[i][j][k] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    // array tetradimensional
    int valores4[3][3][3][3];
    longitud=sizeof(valores4)/sizeof(valores4[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<longitud; j++) {
            for (int k=0; k<longitud; j++) {
                for (int l=0; l<longitud; l++) {
                    valores4[i][j][k][l]=rand() % 100;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Imprimiendo array tetradimensional" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<longitud; j++) {
            cout << "Imprimiendo cubo [" << j+1 << "] de la capa [" << i+1 << "]" << endl;
            for (int k=0; k<longitud; j++) {
                for (int l=0; l<longitud; l++) {
                    cout << valores4[i][j][k][l] << "\t";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}


Hola Gustavo, tienes un typo en el tercer ciclo anidado del array 4D, tienes for (int k=0; k<longitud; j++) y debe ser for (int k=0; k<longitud; k++), estas incrementando j y no k. El error esta en los dos bloques de  for 's anidados, en el que inicializa array y en que lo imprime.

Ese typo hace que ese tercer ciclo anidado sea un ciclo infinito ya que k será siempre 0, pero  al incrementar j indefinicamente valores4[i][j]... intentará acceder a memoria fuera de los límites del array y eventualmente fuera incluso de la memoria que el sistema operativo asignó a tu proceso, la violacíón de segmento.

No es cosa de tu computadora. El asunto es que C++ es bastante permisivo. En  otros lenguajes en vez de un segfault obtendrías un error llamado IndexOutOfBounds o algo así

Gustavo, se me olvido mencionar lo que comenta Mateo. Estás usando memoria estática y en este caso un programa por lo general no va a fallar por falta de memoria en tiempo de ejecución, sino que exec* fallará al iniciarse, hay casos en los que puedes terminar con corrupciones de memoria y otros galimatías, pero de cualquier forma no es tu caso.  En C++ con los arrays "heredados de C" acceder a un indice fuera del array es un comportamiento indefinido, básicamente el estándar no define que debe pasar y por tanto depende del compilador de turno.

En general, si te sales de los limites del array puedes estar accediendo a memoria del propio proceso (obteniendo valores "aleatorios" o corrompiendo memoria) o intentar acceder a memoria que el SO a reservado para el u otros programas y acabar con un SF. Los comportamientos indefinidos y los errores de memoria (mención especial a las fugas) son dos granades "amigos" de cualquier programador de c/c++.

Hay herramientas que te pueden ayudar a identificar estos casos (muchos de ellos silenciosos, los peores), como Sanitizers o Valgrind. Por ejemplo, en tu caso compilar con g++ -Wall -g -fsanitize=bounds-strict -fsanitize=address te generará un runtime error: index out of bounds indicandote fila y columna en el codigo que genera el error así como información detallada del SF.

@FJSevilla Todo eso puede ir en una respuesta. Así le ahorramos al usuario Comunidad que tenga que estar bumpeando.

Es verdad, ya me dí cuenta de "for (int k=0; k<longitud; j++)", voy a probarlo ahora.

Quisiera mencionar que, cuando hablamos de lenguajes compilados, usualmente al código fuente no se le llama script, sino programa. Al menos, en mi experiencia, scirpt se usa en lenguajes interpretados (python, javascript, pascalscript, etc), por lo que cuando leo script y veo la etiqueta [tag:c++], hacen corto circuito algunas neuronas en mi cerebro.

El error ocurre porque el bucle anidado utiliza la variable j para incrementar dentro de otro bucle controlado por k. Esto hace que j se incremente repetidamente, superando los límites del array, mientras que k permanece inalterado.
El error en el código que presenta falla de segmentación es debido a un problema de incremento de variables en los bucles anidados. El bucle interno utiliza la variable j para incrementar, mientras que el bucle externo controla la variable k de manera que j se incrementa repetidamente, superando los límites del array, mientras k permanece inalterado.
Erro
for (int k = 0; k < longitud; j++) {
 
}

La corrección es incrementar debidamente cada variable
 for (int k = 0; k < longitud; k++) {}

observe dónde ocurre el error:
 // array tetradimensional
    int valores4[3][3][3][3];
    longitud=sizeof(valores4)/sizeof(valores4[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<longitud; j++) { //OKAY --- incrementa "j"
            for (int k=0; k<longitud; j++) { /// ----- incrementa de nuevo, "j"
                for (int l=0; l<longitud; l++) {
                    valores4[i][j][k][l]=rand() % 100;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Imprimiendo array tetradimensional" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<longitud; j++) { // OKAY ---> INCREMENTA
            cout << "Imprimiendo cubo [" << j+1 << "] de la capa [" << i+1 << "]" << endl;
            for (int k=0; k<longitud; j++) {// [ERROR] INCREMENTA "J"  DE NUEVO
                for (int l=0; l<longitud; l++) {
                    cout << valores4[i][j][k][l] << "\t";
                }
                cout <<


Gracias a las dos observaciones que me hicieron pude correr el programa tranquilamente, claro que antes elimine los arrays anteriores y deje el de 4 dimensiones, eso por si las dudas.
Es dificil para nuestro cerebro diseñado para un mundo que se rige en tres dimensiones proyectarse a una cuarta dimensión o 5ta o 6ta, la representación que le podemos dar sería una colección de cubos en capas y si vamos más allá sería una coleccion de capas de capas de cubos y así hasta el infinito.
Pero, me sirve este pequeño programa del array de cuatro dimensiones, ya que me informa el número de array y en que capa se encuentra, más o menos para tener una idea de como trata C++ singuaridades más allá de nuestra limitada 3ra dimensión.
Ahi les dejo la imagen del programa depurado y el acuse del array 4 en la capa 4.
En fin, gracias por sus observaciones amigos y yo me voy a sguir proyectando en dimensiones hasta que explote mi cerebro o la máquina.



Como curiosidad, las computadoras no tienen noción sobre diferentes dimensiones. En memoria los elementos de un arreglo ocupan posiciones contiguas. Moverse en otra dimensión se traduce en avanzar con pasos más grandes.

Es correcto, eso lo tengo totalmente claro, por eso, en mi comentario puse "más o menos para tener una idea de como trata C++ singuaridades más allá de nuestra limitada 3ra dimensión"
